# how to run a membber function with QtConcurrrent Qt6? type 'decay_t cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members)

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtconcurrent, qfuture

i'm trying to run a member function but but i got an error , help me please

i tried with this line of code

QFuture<qlonglong> future = QtConcurrent::run(this,&backD::analysa);

[image: this is a screen shot 'lol' of the errors]
and analysa() is a methode that returns a qlonglong

Comment: Please include the error message as text (images are hard to search for if someone else will have the same problem in the future) and try to create a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, but in the picture, I can see `QtConcurrent::run(this->analysa());` which is something else than you wrote... Btw. what is `this` in your case? Have you also tried lambda form `QtConcurrent::run([this]{ analysa(); });`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `QtConcurrent::run([this]{ return analysa(); });` or `QtConcurrent::run([this] -> qlonglong { return analysa(); });`, whichever compiles in your case.

Answer (score 0):

i tried many version before asking here and the QtConcurrent::run(this->analysa()); is one of them, i'ts looks like the lambda form works only with void and i'm using qlonglong.
her is my the member methode analysa

```
 qlonglong  backD::analysa()
{
QString currentPath = tabWidget::currentWidget()->fsCurrentPath();
qlonglong size=0;

QDirIterator it(currentPath,QStringList()<<"*.*",QDir::Files,QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while(it.hasNext())
{


    QFileInfo infos(it.next());

    size += infos.size();

}
return size;}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ok, I updated the lambda version to a full answer. Please check if it wrks now.